# How can I send an adaptive card to specific channel with bot?

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, microsoft-teams-js

I want to send an adaptive card to specific channel using bot.
I used webhook and it was easy to achieve this, but I have to use bot for curtain scenario in stead of webhook.

When `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction` is invoked by submit action, it returns an error: `Unable to extract ConnectorClient from turn context.`

my current code is:

```
 public async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction(
    context: TurnContext,
    action: MessagingExtensionAction
  ): Promise<MessagingExtensionActionResponse> {
    
  ///other code

   const channelId = 123456

    // Construct a conversation reference with the desired channel ID
    const conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(
      context.activity
    );

    conversationReference.conversation.id = channelId;

    await context.sendActivity(sentCard);

    return {};
  }
```

I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/notification-bot-in-teams?tabs=ts1%2Cts2%2Cts3%2Cts4%2Cjsts%2Cts5) and other microsoft teams documentation, but I'm not sure which information I should follow. What I'm trying to do is very simple, just send the adaptive card to specific channel, but I'm confused because it's a lot of information all over the place and it's hard to find information that fits my scenario.

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this: `await turnContext.sendActivity({ attachments: [userCard] });`

Please refer below sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/msgext-message-reminder/nodejs/bots/teamsBot.js#L55